# Cant cast subclass on MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation

I'm having a string in my `FBSingleClusterView` called `companyString`. However i can't seem to access because the `MKAnnotationView` won't be changed to my `FBSingleClusterView`?

**My Code**

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)  
    pinView = FBSingleClusterView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId) as FBSingleClusterView
    pinView.companyString = singleAnnotation.name

}
```

However i keep getting following error `value of type MKAnnotationView has no member companyString`.

Why come it isn't being casted into a `FBSingleClusterView`, which is a subclass of the MKAnnotationView?

**FBSingleClusterView**

```
class FBSingleClusterView: MKAnnotationView {

    var bubbleView: BubbleView?
    var addressString: String?
    var companyString: String?
    var logoImage: UIImage?

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?){
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        // change the size of the cluster image based on number of stories


        backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        setNeedsLayout()


    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {

        // Images are faster than using drawRect:

        centerOffset = CGPointMake(0, -image!.size.height/2);

    }
}
```

Comment: Provide more code, show `FBSingleClusterView` class, maybe it doesn't have `companyString` property or isn't inherited from MKAnnotationView

Comment: You seem to create var pinView using the dequeue... that will end up an inferred type of  MKAnnotationView to the pinView. This line is redundant as in the very next line, you seem to assign a FBSingleClusterView to it. So just remove first assignment. and instead say var pinView = FBSingleClusterView(...

Comment: @katleta3000 i've added FBSingleClusterView now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line is

```
var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
```

As such, pinView is now type MKAnnotationView?

```
Why come it isn't being casted into a FBSingleClusterView, which is a subclass of the MKAnnotationView?
```

Once a var type is set, you cannot reassign another type.

Suggested solution would be

```
if let pinView:FBSingleClusterView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? FBSingleClusterView
{
      pinView.companyString = singleAnnotation.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (I replaced your vars on "test"):

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var pinView: FBSingleClusterView! = nil
    if let reuseView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("test") as? FBSingleClusterView {
        pinView = reuseView
    } else {
        pinView = FBSingleClusterView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "test")
    }
    pinView.companyString = "Test"
    return pinView
}
```

Your problem is in type casting